# RegularGridInterpolator fails when one of the dimensions has only one point

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

In my application, the user can define the points and values and then my code should offer interpolation for them. But the list of dimensions is fixed by the top level requirements. So if the user doesn't want to vary in one of the dimensions they just provide a single value. This seems to break the scipy interpolation. See code.

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
rgi = interp.RegularGridInterpolator(([0],[0,1]), [[3,4]], bounds_error=True)
rgi([0, 0])  # returns nan
rgi = interp.RegularGridInterpolator(([0,1],[0,1]), [[3,4],[5,6]], bounds_error=True)
rgi([0, 0])  # returns 3. as expected
```

Note that the query in both cases is within the bounds.

How can I tell scipy to handle both cases?

Comment: in your first call to the interpolator the first point on your grid only has 1 dimension is that a typo? I get a runtime warning with the first call  **invalid value encountered in true_divide (grid[i + 1] - grid[i]))**

Comment: Interesting addition: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7560

Comment: @DrBwts it's not a typo but thanks for the extra info for the question and well spotted. It's probably a symptom of the same thing, i.e. RGI doesn't support unitary dimensions.